# Ordenação Array PHP

Tags: php, array

Como posso resolver o seguinte problema:

Possuo 4 arrays que são concatenados (**array_merge**) e viram apenas um, porém, agora preciso concatenar os vetores de uma forma diferente.

Preciso pegar o índice 1 de cada array, depois o índice 2, e assim sucessivamente. (**Nem todos tem a  mesma quantidade de índices**) até preencher um único array.

Comment: cade os `arrays` em um exemplo minimo? poderia postar na sua pergunta?

Comment: Descrevendo o problema geral você vai conseguir apenas uma resposta geral. Exemplo: "Como construir uma casa?", "Use blocos e cimento, construa paredes sólidas.". Em vez disso pergunte algo específico e respondível de forma útil: "Como levantar uma parede usando esse tipo de bloco com tal inclinação e de tal altura de forma segura?", resposta: "Posicione os blocos no formato tal, execute esse algoritmo de colocação de blocos, não use essa ferramenta pois há o risco tal, aqui tem um exemplo funcionando de uma parede pronta para você ver como faz [link]". Vê? Perguntas muito amplas não ajudam.

Comment: Entendo, eu particularmente não gosto de pedir ajuda com códigos, pelo fato de pessoas acharem que estou me aproveitando, neste caso gostaria apenas de mais cabeças para pensar em uma solução.

Comment: Pode fazer isso com `array_map()`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Não programo em PHP mas fiz um algoritmo super simples que resolve o problema com javascript.

Basicamente ele verifica qual o array mais longo e faz um for em cima do tamanho máximo. Em cada passada pelo looping ele verifica se cada um dos arrays possui o índice atual e adiciona em um novo array.

```
var a = [1,2,3,4,5];
var b = ['a','b','c'];
var c = ['aa','bb','cc','dd','ee','ff'];

var elem = document.getElementById('new_array');

var new_array = [];

var max_length = 0;

// Verifica qual o maior array    
if (a.length > b.length && a.length > c.length) {
    max_length = a.length;
} else if (b.length > a.length && b.length > c.length) {
    max_length = b.length;
} else {
    max_length = c.length;
}

// Percorre todos os arrays com base no maior deles
// Verifica se o indice atual existe e adiciona ao novo array
for (var i = 0; i < max_length; i++) {
  if (a[i]) {
    new_array.push(a[i]);
  }

  if (b[i]) {
    new_array.push(b[i]);
  }

  if (c[i]) {
    new_array.push(c[i]);
  }
}

elem.innerHTML = JSON.stringify(new_array)
```

Output: `[1,"a","aa",2,"b","bb",3,"c","cc",4,"dd",5,"ee","ff"]`

Comment: Leandro, obrigado, era exatamente isso que você citou. testei isso em código php e funcionou perfeitamente. No inicio achei que essa opção era inviável pois iria estourar em algum dos vetores o index, mas com seu if antes de atribuir solucionou o problema.